# Selenium, HttpClient or java.net package

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, httpclient

I have a requirement where I want to navigate to website , login to it ,click few links  and download some excel files from the one link.

I need to do this in java.I researched on google and seeing few options like selenium, http client ,java.net APIs.

Could you please suggest which one would work better in this case.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will personally prefer Apache http client. you can fetch data using httpclient why use a web testing framework like selenium ? java.net is also good but apache httpClient API has rich functions and easy.

Comment: I want to do session management as well for this i.e. user would navigate through links only after successful login.Do you think httpclient would be better for this kind of requirement too?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest Selenium. More widely used and supported. You can use WebDriver in Selenium. For more details check

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/